# Debugging c code and pointers

Tags: c, pointers

On debugging the following two codes, first one shall print  `1 1` and second one `2 1`, Can I please get explanation for this?
I do have moderate knowledge of pointers but I don't seem to understand this.

#### 1.

```
void main() 
{
    int i = 257; 
    int *iPtr = &i; 
    printf("%d %d", *((char*)iPtr), *((char*)iPtr+1) );
}
```

#### 2.

```
void main() 
{
    int i = 258; 
    int *iPtr = &i; 
    printf("%d %d", *((char*)iPtr), *((char*)iPtr+1) );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In little-endian systems, here are how are stored the values `257` and `258` in memory:

```
257 = 0x101

0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00

byte 0, byte 1, byte 2, byte 3


258 = 0x102

0x02 0x01 0x00 0x00

byte 0, byte 1, byte 2, byte 3
```

Comment: Could you please give some reference on how you divided a memory 0x101 into 0x01, 0x01, ox00, 0x00, please?

Comment: @simokaur See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness they show examples of how is 32-bit value `0x0A0B0C0D` stored in memory in little and big-endian systems.

Answer (score 0):

oh, when you add 1 in `*((char*)iPtr+1)` you add 1 to address, and then dereference it.
in x86 processors use little-endian order, cause your 257 in memory is as: `0x1,0x1,0x0,0x0`; 258 as `0x2,0x1,0x0,0x0`.